# MySQL Server install fails when the latest Visual C++ Redistributable Package is already installed

Tags: windows-10, installation, mysql

[image]

I'm on a **Dell Latitude** laptop with fresh **Windows 10** (it just updated), and I'm installing all the things. One of those things is MySQL via the oracle installer.

MySQL required c++ redistributables, so I have installed both 2013 and 2015 redistributables, and the MySQL installer has successfully installed several programs, one of which being Workbench, but not MySQL Server.

I have tried googling for *Visual Studio 2013 Redis.* - but that only brings up the c++ redis -should I install VS 2013 CE?

What is MySQL Server wanting from me?

Comment: Check to be sure it's not an x86 vs x64 package of the C++ VS components that are missing. Maybe you have one but not the other and it'd looking for that one that's missing, etc.

Comment: Check here for example: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784 and then when you go to download select one of the other or both versions and try.... Maybe you will get lucky and it'll be as simple as that.

Comment: Both c++ redis' are x64, and I select the x64 MySQL one.

Comment: Good intuition tho - always a good idea to check.

Comment: Okay, so try installing the x86 C++ VS redist package even though MySQL is x64 and it may be what it's looking for. I see no harm in trying just in case if you know what I'm saying.

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS.

Post that x86, same download link, as the answer. That is _so_ annoying. #software #x86 #x64 #nothingMatters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hop on over to [VisualStudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/) and download both **x86** and the **x64** *or whichever you may not already have installed*.

Sometimes software prerequisite checks will require the **x86** versions of packages even when the **x64** version of the product is what is being installed.

Simply download the package for the CPU architecture which you do not already have installed and then afterwards re-run the **MySQL** Server install again and maybe the prerequisite check will pass.

---

### Further Resources

- [VisualStudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/)

Comment: There are multiple questions, with answers to the download page for the Visual C++ packages, the problem is the download page has changed recently.  While the link to this particular version is correct, today, a better link to use might be [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/) one.  [This](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/) will be updated in the future, the old links to say Visual C++ 2010, simply do not work still have not updated to redirect to the new location as of today.

Comment: @Ramhound Good point and suggestion—answer updated!!

Comment: Although it has recently been updated, even [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) link, does not link to the correct download page for the older versions.  So apparently this page was actually updated.  When I last checked it, it still linked to the old MS CDN website, instead of the VS CDN

Comment: Gosh, dem sneaky Microsoft download links.

Comment: It took me about 15 days to figure out, what the heck happen to the downloads.  Visual C++ 2013 is an exception, the other versions, have to go through the visual studio website. In addition, the older versions of Visual Studio itself, have to be downloaded from that same website.